# Integral, Polar Coordinate Converting Upper and Lower Bounds.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Calculate Using Polar Coordinates**

This is a drawing I made to illustrate the problem. http://tube.geogebra.org/m/ZzvL0a38

$$\int_{\frac 12}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} 1 \quad dydx $$

What I am confused about in this problem is how does one redefine the upper and lower bound coordinates? From what I can see this is a type 1 domain. I know that I am supposed to use the unit circle, but I am unsure on how to proceed.

This is what I have so far

$$\iint r dr dϴ $$

Comment: Why don't you just integrate the problem in its original form?

Comment: According the book one must convert the problem classify it as type I or type II then proceed to integrate.

Comment: The picture does not look right. We want the area of the first quadrant part of the circle which is to the right of the vertical line $x=\frac{1}{2}$. This area can be found in various ways. Polar coordinates  are not necessarily the simplest way.

Comment: @LittleJon What book are you using? You can just integrate the original problem in $y$ and then use a trig substitution for the integral in $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{\frac 12}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} 1 \quad dydx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_{1-0.5\sec\theta}^{1}  \quad rdrd\theta$$
[image]
some details:

---

$$x=0.5$$
$$r\cos\theta=0.5$$
$$r=0.5\sec\theta$$

Comment: Could you please explain where the secant came from and the  $\frac π3$ ?

Comment: I suppose that the inferior limit is $0.5 \sec \theta$. I'm wrong?

Comment: @LittleJon see the some details

Comment: No you are right why is the inferior limit negative when it is  $\frac 12$secϴ?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{2}≤x≤1$

$0≤y≤\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Sketch the region which satisfies the above. Then change the region from $dy dx$ to $dx dy$. The limits become $\frac{1}{2}≤x≤\sqrt{1-y^2}$ and $0≤y≤\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

As suggested above integrating it without changing limits is probably easier.

Comment: But if you integrate as it is wont you get a different answer?

Comment: You get the same answer but leaving the integral as you are given and integrating it is probably quicker

Comment: So theoretically as long as you know it is a type 1 or type 2. Then you can just bypass the changing of the limits?  When will there be a situation when changing it is necessary and not unavoidable?

Comment: Sometimes they will tell you when you need to change limits. But otherwise try integrating it and you might come to a standstill with the integral. Then first check your working , if it is correct then change limits and hopefully the integral is much easier to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

From elementar trigonometry we see that the area is $A=\dfrac {\pi}{6}-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{8}$ where $ \dfrac {\pi}{6}$ is the area of the circular segment of central angle $\theta =\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ and  $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{8}$ is the area of the triangle of basis $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and height $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

We can find this with a double integral in polar coordinates using the figure in the answer of E.H.E., but with a little change of the limits of integration ( the radius goes from $\dfrac{1}{2\cos \theta}$, on the vertical line thorough $x=1/2$, to $1$, on the circle):

$$
A=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int _{\frac{1}{2\cos \theta}}^1 r dr d \theta=
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\dfrac{1}{2}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{4\cos^2 \theta} \right) d \theta=
$$
$$
=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}d \theta -\dfrac{1}{8}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \dfrac{1}{\cos^2 \theta} d \theta=\dfrac{\pi}{6}-\dfrac{1}{8}\left( \tan (\pi/3)-\tan(0) \right)=\dfrac{\pi}{6}-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{8}
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\left[\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}1\space\text{d}y\right]\space\text{d}x=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\left[\left[y\right]_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right]\space\text{d}x=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

For the integrand $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, substitute $x=\sin(u)$ and $\text{d}x=\cos\space\text{d}u$.

Then $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(u)}=\sqrt{\cos^2(u)}$.

This substitution is invertible over $\frac{\pi}{6}<u<\frac{\pi}{2}$ with inverse $u=\arcsin(x)$.

This gives a new lower bound $u=\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and upper bound $u=\arcsin(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$:

---

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(u)\sqrt{\cos^2(u)}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Simplify $\cos(u)\sqrt{\cos^2(u)}$ assuming $\frac{\pi}{6}<u<\frac{\pi}{2}$:

---

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2(u)\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos(2u)+\frac{1}{2}\right)\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(2u)\space\text{d}u+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1\space\text{d}u$$